# HTML google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Good afternoon,

I'm new to google script and would like to know how I can get data from an HTML form and put it in a document. I need to put the data into the cube in the title of a file that is created at the click of a button. Thank you.

Comment: Read about [Client to Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). With google.script.run.anyfunctionname in an html file you can call any script in your container(i.e. spreadsheet, doc).

Answer (score 1):

The following project might be helpful for your problem.

https://github.com/terrywbrady/PlainTextCSV_GoogleAppsScript

In this code, a Google App Script project is deployed as a web app.

The doGet() method returns an html page with a form.

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return html;
}
```

The html page has a submit function that invokes the following function.

```
  function handleFormPost(formObject) {
    jQuery("input:button").attr("disabled",true);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
      .withFailureHandler(fail).doTextPost(formObject);
  }
```

This function calls the doTextPost() method in the App Script code.

```
function doTextPost(req) {
  var name = getParam(req, "name", "");
  var folderid = getParam(req, "folderid", "");
  var delim = getParam(req, "delim", ",");
  var resp = createPlainTextSpreadsheet(req.data, name, folderid, delim);
  return JSON.stringify(resp);
}
```

The success handler defined on the html page processes the JSON data returned from this function.

```
  function updateOutput(data) {
    var resp  = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="<a href='"+resp.url+"'>"+resp.name+"</a> created on Google Drive";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this code will be quite useful, but I'm still confused as to which part of my code I'm going to have to change.